# Reliably convert comma/semi-colon separated list of "last, first, last, first," names

Tags: python

I have a large list of names, with the entries that contain multiple names being separated by either comma or semi-colon, or even occasionally not. For instance:

```
First Last
Last, First
Last, First, A.
Last, First Middle
Last, First, Last, First A., Last, First, Ph.D, Last, First, M.D., Last, J. R, Last, O.
Last, First Middle plus other names, Last, First, Jr., Last, First, Sr.
Last, First; Last, First A.; Last, First Middle 
First Last, First Last, First A. Last, Last, First
```

I'm trying to create a function, as I pass in each entry individually, that would reliably return a list, with everything properly ordered as "First Last" with any possible suffixes like Jr, M.D, etc. So far, from another SO question, I have:

```
def fix_names(names):
    if ',' in names:
        names = [b.strip() + ' ' + a.strip()
                   for a, b in zip(*[iter(names.split(','))] * 2)]
    return names
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
['First Last']
['First Last', 'First A. Last', 'First Last, Ph.D', 'First Last, Jr.'] etc
```

If I strip suffixes such as ", M.D" first and don't keep them, most of the time it works. For instance taking one example without prefixes:

```
Last, First, Last, First A., Last, First, Last, First, Last, J. R., Last, O.
```

I get:

```
['First Last', 'First A. Last', 'First Last', 'First Last', 'J. R. Last', 'O. Last']
```

Yet another case such as "Last, First A." turns out as ['First Last']. For the cases that might be "First Last, First Last", I don't necessarily mind if it's reversed since it's more rare and I can fix them later if needed. I am also processing semi-colons and commas in separate steps since I'm not sure if it's easy to split once, and then go through each value, and add to the list if a split is needed again.

Comment: Can you give a simple example about what works and what doesn't; with real and expected results?

Comment: This only addresses the first part of your question, but how about using a regex to pull out the names with suffixes, something like (this is untested, rearrange and modify as needed given your inputs): `(?<first>[A-Z]\.?\w*\-?[A-Z]?\w*)\s?(?<middle>[A-Z]\w*|[A-Z]?\.?)\s?(?[A-Z]\w*\-?[A-Z]?\w*)(?:,\s|)(?<last>Jr\.|M\.D\.|\.|Ph\.D|)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult parsing problem, but here is a rough sketch that does reasonably well.

```
import sys
import re

SUFFIXES = set('''
    Ph.D
    M.D.
    Jr.
    Sr.
'''.split())

regexes = dict(
    punct  = re.compile(r'\s*[;,]\s*'),
    space  = re.compile(r'\s*'),
    middle = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]\.?$'),
)

def main(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            for name in parse_line(line):
                print name

def parse_line(line):
    tokens = get_tokens(line.strip())
    name = []
    for t in tokens:
        if t in SUFFIXES:
            name.append(t)
        elif regexes['middle'].search(t):
            name.append(t)
        elif len(name) > 1:
            yield name
            name = [t]
        else:
            name.append(t)
    if name:
        yield name

def get_tokens(line):
    k = 'punct' if (';' in line or ',' in line) else 'space'
    return regexes[k].split(line.strip())

main(sys.argv[1])
```

The results are not perfect. It is not clear how one could distinguish the three problem cases notes below (#1, #2, and #3) without building more name intelligence into the algorithm. When you see a token that contains whitespace, is it a FIRST-MIDDLE combo or a FIRST-LAST combo? That ambiguity trips up the logic that groups tokens together to form a name for one person. You could check the tokens for whitespace: if they have any, split on that (which would solve #2 and #3), but it would make #1 worse.

```
['First', 'Last']
['Last', 'First']
['Last', 'First', 'A.']
['Last', 'First Middle']
['Last', 'First']
['Last', 'First A.']
['Last', 'First', 'Ph.D']
['Last', 'First', 'M.D.']
['Last', 'J. R']
['Last', 'O.']
['Last', 'First Middle plus other names']    # 1
['Last', 'First', 'Jr.']
['Last', 'First Sr.']
['Last', 'First']
['Last', 'First A.']
['Last', 'First Middle']
['First Last', 'First Last']                 # 2
['First A. Last', 'Last']
['First']                                    # 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. The desired output is ['First Last']. Perhaps splitting with re.split(r'[;,\s]\s*', names) and then reordering any matches in list of suffixes before re-combining?

Comment: @empedocle Splitting early on whitespace helps with some cases, but it will tend to cause trouble with `'First Middle'` situations -- maybe a worthwhile tradeoff, depending on the details of the full data set. Good luck either way!